# boost::unordered_map maintains order of insertion?

Tags: c++, boost, containers

I am looking for a container which provides std::map like interface but maintains the order in which elements are inserted. Since there will not be too many elements in the map, the lookup performance is not a big issue. Will [boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html)  work in this case? i.e. does it maintain the order of insertion. I am new to boost library and hence want to know what exactly meant by 'unordered' ?

Comment: Why not just try? :) experimentation isn't that bad.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Check my answer to this other question and see if it applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570349/which-stl-container

Comment: @LiraNuna: Because that just tells you about the behavior in your current implementation and not whether this specific behavior is required and can be relied upon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

unordered_map doesn't maintain the order of insertion. Unordered in this case means that the observable order of elements (i.e. when you enumerate them) is unspecified and arbitrary. In fact, I would expect that the order of elements in an unordered_map can change during the lifetime of the map, due to rehashing when resizing the map (that's implementation dependent though)

Answer (score 19):

Read about [Boost.Multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). It gives you an opportunity to create a container that has both access to data by key (like std::map) and sequenced acess to data (like std::list).

This is an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/example/sequenced.cpp).

Answer (score 6):

When I needed this last time, I used a `std::vector< std::pair<const Key, Value> >`. I didn't need much of the `std::map` interface so I didn't bother with is, but it seems it should be fairly easy to slap a map-like interface around this.

Also, be sure to look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454762/454782).