# What are differences between List, Dictionary and Tuple in Python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between list, dictionary and tuple in Python exactly?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set: In Python, when to use a Dictionary, List or Set?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 53):

A list can store a sequence of objects in a certain order such that you can index into the list, or iterate over the list. List is a mutable type meaning that lists can be modified after they have been created.

A tuple is similar to a list except it is immutable. There is also a semantic difference between a list and a tuple. To quote [Nikow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python/626871#626871):

> Tuples have structure, lists have order.

A dictionary is a key-value store. It is not ordered and it requires that the keys are hashable. It is fast for lookups by key.