# What is the difference between {} and [] in python?

Tags: python, syntax

What is the difference between `columnNames = {}` and `columnNames = []` in python?

How can i iterate each one? using  `{% for value in columnNames  %}` OR `for idx_o, val_o in enumerate(columnNames):`

Comment: Have you had a chance to look through the tutorial yet?

Comment: You should add the `django` tag, since the first looping syntax is Django template speech.

Comment: sorry I'm new in Python, and only heard about arrays and lists, haven't heard about dictionary.

Comment: i don't think that the question was django specific, i think OP came across some django doc showing the templates syntax, and it led to a misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry for that {% Django tags

Comment: [please check the list dictionary and tuple details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649841/what-are-differences-between-list-dictionary-and-tuple-in-python)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- `columnNames = {}` defines an empty `dict`
- `columnNames = []` defines an empty `list`

These are fundamentally different types. A `dict` is an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), a `list` is a [standard array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type) with integral indices.

I recommend you consult your reference material to become more familiar with these two very important Python container types.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to David's answer here is how you usually iterate them:

```
# iterating over the items of a list
for item in someList:
    print( item )

# iterating over the keys of a dict
for key in someDict:
    print( key, someDict[key] )

# iterating over the key/value pairs of a dict
for ( key, value ) in someDict.items():
    print( key, value )
```