# Problems in memoization Fibonacci sequences in Python

Tags: python

I am implementing a Fibonacci sequence with Python. And I used an array ("[]") for memoization, but I get an `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.

However, using an object ("{}") works fine. What's the difference?

**code**

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        memo[n] = n

    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)

    return memo[n]


# memo = [] not work.
# memo = {} work.

print(fib(6))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between {} and \[\] in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230874/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-python)

Comment: `[]` creates a `list`, while `{}` creates a `dict`.  A `list` is just an array, with contiguous elements.  There are no holes in a list.  A `dict` is a hash table.  It's less efficient than a `list`, but it only requires storage for the elements that you need (plus some overhead), and the keys can be any un-mutable values (not just integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do **memo = []** it doesn't have any elements in it.
and when you send **fib(2)** its actually doing

```
memo[2] = n
```

which will throw an error **list index out of range**, because memo doesnt have any element at index **2**

When you do **memo = {}**, its creating a dict and

```
memo[2] = n
```

will add a new key **2** with value **n** it it. like this:

```
memo = {
  2: n
}
```