# Python Comparing 2 list and 2 tuple with equality sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hash, tuples

Recently I have been learning more about hashing in Python and I came around this [blog](https://www.journaldev.com/17357/python-hash-function) where it states that:

> Suppose a Python program has 2 lists. If we need to think about
>   comparing those two lists, what will you do? Compare each element?
>   Well, that sounds fool-proof but slow as well!
>
> Python has a much smarter way to do this. When a tuple is constructed
>   in a program, Python Interpreter calculates its hash in its memory. If
>   a comparison occurs between 2 tuples, it simply compares the hash
>   values and it knows if they are equal!

So I am really confused about these statements.

First when we do:
`[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]` then how does this equality works ? Does it calculate the hash value and then compare it ?

Second what's the difference when we do:

`[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]` and `(1, 2, 3) == (1, 2, 3)` ?

Because when I tried to find time of execution with timeit then I got this result:

```
$ python3.5 -m timeit '[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.14 usec per loop
$ python3.5 -m timeit '(1, 2, 3) == (1, 2, 3)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0301 usec per loop
```

So why there is difference in time from `0.14` for list to `0.03` for tuple which is faster than list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python efficiency: lists vs. tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063494/python-efficiency-lists-vs-tuples)

Comment: @RomanKonoval I think the contexts are different so not a dupe of that IMO.

Comment: Equity comparisons for lists does not use hashing of the list, after all lists are not hashable

Comment: I'd suggest not reading anything by that blogger again, because it's nonsense.

Answer (score 7):

Well, part of your confusion is that the blog post you're reading is just wrong. About multiple things. Try to forget that you ever read it (except to remember the site and the author's name so you'll know to avoid them in the future).

It is true that tuples are hashable and lists are not, but that isn't relevant to their equality-testing functions. And it's certainly not true that "it simply compares the hash values and it knows if they are equal!" Hash collisions happen, and ignoring them would lead to horrible bugs, and fortunately Python's developers are not that stupid. In fact, it's not even true that Python computes the hash value at initialization time.<sup>*</sup>

There actually *is* one significant difference between tuples and lists (in CPython, as of 3.6), but it usually doesn't make much difference: Lists do an extra check for unequal length at the beginning as an optimization, but the same check turned out to be a pessimization for tuples,<sup>**</sup> so it was removed from there.

Another, often much more important, difference is that tuple literals in your source get compiled into constant values, and separate copies of the same tuple literal get folded into the same constant object; that doesn't happen with lists, for obvious reasons.

In fact, that's what you're really testing with your `timeit`. On my laptop, comparing the tuples takes 95ns, while comparing the lists takes 169ns—but breaking it down, that's actually 93ns for the comparison, plus an extra 38ns to create each list. To make it a fair comparison, you have to move the creation to a setup step, and then compare already-existing values inside the loop. (Or, of course, you may not *want* to be fair—you're discovering the useful fact that every time you use a tuple constant instead of creating a new list, you're saving a significant fraction of a microsecond.)

Other than that, they basically do the same thing. Translating [the C source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L604) into Python-like pseudocode (and removing all the error handling, and the stuff that makes the same function work for `<`, and so on):

```
for i in range(min(len(v), len(w))):
    if v[i] != w[i]:
        break
else:
    return len(v) == len(w)
return False
```

The [list equivalent](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2578) is like this:

```
if len(v) != len(w):
    return False
for i in range(min(len(v), len(w))):
    if v[i] != w[i]:
        break
else:
    return True
return False
```

---

<sub>* In fact, unlike strings, tuples don't even cache their hashes; if you call `hash` over and over, it'll keep re-computing it. See [issue 9685](https://bugs.python.org/issue9685), where a patch to change that was rejected because it slowed down some benchmarks and didn't speed up anything anyone could find.</sub>

<sub>** Not because of anything inherent about the implementation, but because people often compare lists of different lengths, but rarely do with tuples.</sub>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am not sure why I got down votes but I guess it's my confusion between list and tuples. So I just want to ask that: `When a tuple is constructed in a program, Python Interpreter calculates its hash in its memory.` Is this statement correct for tuples ? That it compares hash value and return answer ?

Comment: @ShashankSharma No, it is not true that it compares the hash value and returns the answer. What it does is basically what I showed in the answer. In fact, it's not even true that Python calculates the hash at construction time and caches it; I'll edit that into the answer as well.

Comment: Well explained, Thanks for the issue link, that really helped me about understanding why they didn't implemented hash on tuples.

Comment: Well dissected, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in that article too :)

here is the demonstrated :

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3]
>>> l2=[1,2,3]
>>> 
>>> hash(l1) #since list is not hashable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> t=(1,2,3)
>>> t2=(1,2,3)
>>> hash(t)
2528502973977326415
>>> hash(t2)
2528502973977326415
>>>
```

in above when you call hash on list it will give you TypeError as it is not hashable and for equality of two list python check its inside value that will lead to take much time

in case of tuple it calculates the hash value and for two similar tuplle having the same hash value so python only compared the hashvalue of tuple so it us much fast than list

from given article

> Python has a much smarter way to do this. When a tuple is constructed
>   in a program, Python Interpreter calculates its hash in its memory. If
>   a comparison occurs between 2 tuples, it simply compares the hash
>   values and it knows if they are equal!

Comment: The OP is aware of this quote - they even cite it in the question. Why would that answer their question?

Comment: @MrT sorry but didnt got u