# How can i change the values in dictionary of lists in python

Tags: python

I hae a dictionary like this

`dict1 = [('var1','aa'),('var2','bb')('var3','cc')]`

I have another dictionary

`dict2 = [('var2','22'),('var3','33'),('var5','23'),('var6','33'),('var7','23')]`

What i want to do is that i to replace the contents of `dict2` with the varibels in dict1

I mean so that final dict3 = `dict2 = [('var2','bb'),('var3','cc'),('var5','23'),('var6','33'),('var7','23')]`

Comment: those aren't dictionaries, they are lists of tuples, convert them to dictionaries with dict(), iterate through the keys and replace.

Comment: @monkut Why didn't you post that as an answer? You beat me to the punch (while I was writing out code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = [('var1','aa'),('var2','bb'),('var3','cc')]
>>> list2 = [('var2','22'),('var3','33'),('var5','23'),('var6','33'),('var7','23')]
>>> dict1 = dict(list1)
>>> list2 = [(k, dict1.get(k, v)) for k, v in list2]
>>> list2
[('var2', 'bb'), ('var3', 'cc'), ('var5', '23'), ('var6', '33'), ('var7', '23')]
```

This will maintain order from the original `list2`

Comment: @user33 Well proves me wrong haha. However, if you are "replacing" the values associated with variables like that, you really should be using a dictionary. Tuples are immutable, and dictionaries are meant for (seemingly) exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @Mathew Actually my other bit code is using the tuple. Initially i didn't need to chnage it. but now i need to make few replacements. so i just prefered as end result be tuple so that i don't need to touch the rest of code. i am new to python so was confsued with dic and tuple. i just wanted to replace the things,  didn't knew if thats dict or tuple. Your solution is also good but this is just what i wanted. As i have written in your comment before i saw this answer

Comment: @user33 I'm just trying to explain why, in the future, you want to use a dictionary for things like this. [Another explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649841/what-are-differences-between-list-dictionary-and-tuple-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

Those are not [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Here is how to do it if they were:

```
>>> dict1 = {'var1':'aa', 'var2':'bb' ,'var3':'cc'}
>>> dict2 = {'var2':'22', 'var3':'33', 'var5':'23', 'var6':'33', 'var7':'23'}
>>> for key in dict2:
...     if key in dict1:
...             dict2[key] = dict1[key]
... 
>>> dict2
{'var5': '23', 'var7': '23', 'var6': '33', 'var3': 'cc', 'var2': 'bb'}
```

You probably want to start out with `dict1` and `dict2` actually being dictionaries as in my example, but note that you can easily convert them using eg. `dict1 = dict(dict1)`.

Comment: can i convert back to tuple after relacing contents

Comment: Yes, just use `[(k, v) for k, v in dict2.items()]`

Comment: Yes, but if you want the final result in that tuple form, just use sberry's answer.

Comment: @sberry: or just `dict2.items()`? The list comprehension isn't needed (although you might have to do `list(dict2.items())` in Python 3).

Comment: @Marius you can't use just `.items()` if you want to maintain order.

Comment: @Marius Though sberry's comment answer does do the same thing as `.items()`. sberry's actual answer does preserve order.