# Python - Finding next element in list matching a condition. Substitute previous entry

Tags: python

I have a list of elements to which I inputted some "identifiable" values that are not to go to my database. I want to find and substitute those values. Code looks like this (tried to be generic and illustrative, the date and time is predefined vars):

```
A = []
A.append(['Name1',date1,time1,0.00])
A.append(['Name1',date1,time2,0.00])
A.append(['Name2',date1,time1,price1])
A.append(['Name1',date1,time3,price2])
A.append(['Name1',date1,time4,price3])
A.append(['Name1',date2,time5,price4])
```

and so on. This 0.00 price should be changed by the next price where we have 'Name1' in position 0 and date1 in position 1, i.e.:

```
print(A[0])
print(A[1])
```

should yield

```
['Name1',date1,time1,price1]
['Name1',date1,time2,price1]
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `append` takes only one argument. Make sure your examples work before posting.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to put the brackets.

Comment: so `date1`,`time1` are `variables` defined already in your code?

Comment: yes.  price1, price2.... and also date2, time2, time3... are also predefined.
sorry if didn't make that clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for printing, pass the list and index for the same.

```
def print1(lists, index):
    if lists[index][3] == 0:
            try:
                    name=lists[index][0]
                    val = next(l[3] for l in lists[index:] if l[3]>0 and l[0]==name)
                    print lists[index][:-1] + [val]
            except:
                    print "No value found with same name where price>0"
    else:
            print lists[index]

A=[]
A.append(['Name1','date1','time1',0.00])
A.append(['Name1','date1','time2',0.00])
A.append(['Name2','date1','time1',10])
A.append(['Name1','date1','time3',20])
A.append(['Name1','date1','time4',30])
A.append(['Name1','date2','time5',40])
print1(A,1)
```

you can return the values in place of printing them in case you need them to.

Comment: Thanks Namit. that was very helpful and should work within the framework I'm programming

Comment: @NamitSingal that's great! This replaces the `0.00` in `(A,1)` I am wondering how to replace all the `0.00` in A based on the same logic if A is a bigger list with similar data. Actually, even in this A it only replaces `0.00` in `(A,1)` not in '(A,0)`. How would you replace in both `(A,1)` and '(A,0)`?

Comment: @JoeR that would be a different scenario, you could use a combination of map and tree to accomplish the same, on first pass store 'Name' as the key, and have a tree with indexes so that we do not replace the value of 'Name' with the previous indices. First pass will populate this DS, second pass we will just keep on filling the values. There can be simpler solution if the exact context of the problem is known.

Comment: @NamitSingal thanks for the answer. I actually thought that's what the OP was trying to accomplish. In any case, good answer!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need a method like this:

```
A = []
def insert_or_update_by_name_and_date(x):
    if not isinstance(x, list) or len(x) < 2:
        return
    for element in A:
        if len(element) < 2:
            continue
        if element[0] == x[0] and element[1] == x[1]:
            element[2] = x[2]
            element[3] = x[3]
            return
    A.append(x)
```

Comment: I forgot the brackets. Sorry.

Comment: however, the prints are for what I intend AFTER modifying with the substitution

Comment: this should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `for` loops:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i, len(A)):
        if A[i][3] == 0.0 and A[j]]0] == 'Name1' and A[j][1] == date1:
            A[i][3] = A[j][3]
```

Apart from that, you may find this discussion on [when to use a Dictionary, List or Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set) useful.