# Inserting variables into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

Why is this code adding the key but not the value for a dictionary in Python?

Here is the result:

```
$ python hashtest.py
set(['yes:no'])
set(['hi', 'yes:no'])
```

And the code is as follows:

```
hashmap={"yes:no"}

print hashmap
var1="hi"
var2="bye"

#hashmap[var1]=var2
#print hashmap

hashmap.update({var1:var2})
print hashmap
```

The first method (`hashmap[var1] = var2`) gave a type error (assignment).

TIA

Comment: `hashmap={"yes:no"}` creates a `set`, not a `dict`. FWIW, a `set` is essentially a `dict` with keys but no values.

Comment: You should use `hashmap = {"yes":"no"}` to create a dictionary, here you're creating a set.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to understand first what kind of **data structure** would you need for your purpose.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set) might be useful. In particular,

> • Use a dictionary when you have a set of unique keys that map to values.
>
> • Use a set to store an unordered set of items.

You can find an extensive explanation in chapter 4 of [High Performance Python](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-python/9781449361747/ch04.html)

In your case, it seems you want to create a `dictionary`, so this should help you out

```
>>> hashmap = {}
>>> hashmap["yes"] = "no"
>>> hashmap
{'yes': 'no'}
>>> var1="hi"
>>> var2="bye"
>>> hashmap[var1] = var2
>>> hashmap
{'yes': 'no', 'hi': 'bye'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change the value of a given key in a dictionary. Here's some code that will do that.

```
>>> mydict = {'hi' : 'hello', 'bye' : 'goodbye', 'see ya' : None }
>>> print mydict
{'bye': 'goodbye', 'hi': 'hello', 'see ya': None}
>>> mydict['see ya'] = mydict['bye']
>>> mydict
{'bye': 'goodbye', 'hi': 'hello', 'see ya': 'goodbye'}
```

Comment: Here's a popular SO link for adding a value to a dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-key-to-a-dictionary-in-python