# Python: How interpreter read Set and find intersection

Tags: python, set, interpreter

I read about `python set`

```
x = set(["a","b","c","d"])
y = set(["c","d"])
print( x.intersection(y) )
```

I am getting output as `{'d', 'c'}` or `{'c', 'd'}` each time.

Though its correct, I am just curious about sequence of `set item`

How interpreter read set?

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because a `set` does not maintain order like a `list` does. Take a look at this link here for a great description of the different Python structures and when to use them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489100/1199721