# Python large array comparison

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-2.7, compare

I have a large array containing URL (it can contains 100 000 URL strings), and I would like to know if my actual URL is one of the URL from the array. For that, I have to compare the actual URL string with all the URL string in the array. Is there any way to compare with this large array but with less time than I do now ? For now it's :

```
error = 0
for oldUrl in urlList:
    error = 1 if oldUrl == actualUrl else error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Laurent and @sisanared, you can use the `in` operator for either `lists` or `sets` to check for membership. For example:

```
found = x in some_list
if found: 
    #do stuff
else:
    #other stuff
```

However, you mentioned that speed is an issue. TL;DR -- `sets` are faster if the `set` already exists. From https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, checking membership using the `in` operator is O(n) for `list` and O(1) for `set` (like @enderland pointed out).

For 100,000 items, or for one-time-only checks it probably doesn't make much of a difference which you use, but for a larger number of items or situations where you'll be doing many checks, you should probably use a `set`. I did a couple of tests from the interpreter and this is what I found (Python 2.7, i3 Windows 10 64bit):

```
import timeit
#Case 1: Timing includes building the list/set
def build_and_check_a_list(n):
    a_list = [ '/'.join( ('http:stackoverflow.com',str(i)) ) for i in xrange(1,n+1) ]
    check = '/'.join( ('http:stackoverflow.com',str(n)) )
    found = check in a_list
    return (a_list, found)

def build_and_check_a_set(n):
    a_set = set( [ '/'.join( ('http:stackoverflow.com',str(i)) ) for i in xrange(1,n+1) ] )
    check = '/'.join( ('http:stackoverflow.com',str(n)) )
    found = check in a_set
    return (a_set, found)

timeit.timeit('a_list, found = build_and_check_a_list(100000)', 'from __main__ import build_and_check_a_list', number=50)
3.211972302022332

timeit.timeit('a_set, found = build_and_check_a_set(100000)', 'from __main__ import build_and_check_a_set', number=50)
4.5497120006930345

#Case 2: The list/set already exists (timing excludes list/set creation)
check = '/'.join( ('http:stackoverflow.com',str(100000)) )

timeit.timeit('found = check in a_list', 'from __main__ import a_list, check', number=50)
0.12173540635194513

timeit.timeit('found = check in a_set', 'from __main__ import a_set, check', number=50)
1.01052391983103e-05
```

For 1 million entries, to build and/or check membership on my computer:

```
#Case 1: list/set creation included
timeit.timeit('a_list, found = build_and_check_a_list(1000000)', 'from __main__ import build_and_check_a_list', number=50)
35.71641090788398

timeit.timeit('a_set, found = build_and_check_a_set(1000000)', 'from __main__ import build_and_check_a_set', number=50)
51.41244436103625

#Case 2: list/set already exists
check = '/'.join( ('http:stackoverflow.com',str(1000000)) )

timeit.timeit('found = check in a_list', 'from __main__ import a_list, check', number=50)
1.3113457772124093

timeit.timeit('found = check in a_set', 'from __main__ import a_set, check', number=50)
8.180430086213164e-06
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a `list` contains an `item`, use: `item in list`.

So, you can write:

```
error = oldUrl in urlList
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a list for this. Lookups in lists have a worst case complexity of O(n).

Use a set (or dictionary if you have other metadata) instead. This has a lookup of roughly O(1). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3489071/1048539) for comparisons between a set, dictionary, and list.

Using a set, the lookup is simple:

```
urls = set(['url1', 'url2', 'url3'])

print ('url2' in urls)
print ('foobar' in urls)
```

Or in your case, convert your list object as a set:

```
urlListSet = set(urlList)
print(oldUrl in urlListSet)
```

You can also add new urls to your set:

```
urlListSet.add(newurl)
urlListSet.update(listOfNewUrls)
```