# Doubts in python code how to use set method

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I was excepting all the elements to print but it prints only `HFFDFD` and `fjdkl`. why does this happens. Here's my code:

```
print (set({'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you **iterate over a dictionary**, you **only obtain the keys**. Next you put all these keys into a set that you print.

You can however use the following *set comprehension* to print both keys and values:

```
d = {'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616}
print(set(y for x in d.items() for y in x))
```

Now you will construct a set that contains both keys and values.

If you however wish to print the dictionary itself, you can simply use:

```
print ({'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616})
```

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `dict` instead of set. Try this:

```
>>> print (dict({'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616}))
{'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616}
```

EDIT: In fact, that is already a `dict` so you can just do:

```
>>> print ({'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616})
{'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616}
```

You are confusing `set` with `dict`. You can see a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set).

And if you want to sequentially print all the values and not the as a `dict`, you can do this:

```
>>> dct = {'Hffdfd' : 'shfs', 'fjdkl' : 616}
>>> for x in dct:
>>>   print(x)
>>>   print(dct[x])
Hffdfd
shfs
fjdkl
616
```