# Dictionary to Tab Delimited Text File for Particular Schema

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
data = {'a':'one','b':'two','c':'three'}
```

I want to convert this to a tab delimited text file such that the file reads as:

```
a    b    c    one    two    three.
```

I tried:

```
import json

data = {'a':'one','b':'two','c':'three'}

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
 file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

However the resulting file just reads as `('a':'one','b':'two','c':'three')`. I knew it wouldn't be as simple as that, and I'm sure it's not complex, but I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Do you want all the keys *and* values in *one* row, as six columns?

Comment: I suppose that the `csv` module should be used, setting delimiter to tab.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, absolutely. Also, for learning purposes, if I was to have more than one dictionary, how could I create a text file so that the schema is the same but just on the proceeding row?

Comment: If you wanted a tab delimited file, why did you use JSON? Also that's *not* what the file would look like.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, actually my data was imported from a json file, but I wanted to convert dictionary objects to string and one way to do it would be `json.dumps(data)`, I may be wrong, I'm pretty new to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
data = {'a':'one','b':'two','c':'three'}
s = ""
for x in data.keys():
  s += x
  s += "\t"
for x in data.values():
  s += x
  s += "\t"
print(s)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(s)
```

Dictionary is a structure that's designed for when a one-to-one association between values exist. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set) to further discussions on how it compares with other structures.

Therefore it makes sense to print the `key:value` pair together to preserve that association. Thus the default behaviour of `print(data)` or in your case `file.write(data)` when data is a dictionary is to output `{'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'three'}`.

The `key1, key2, ... value1, value2 ...` type of output format you request is not typical for a structure like dictionary, therefore a more "manual" approach like the one above involving two loops is required.

As for `json`, its usage is really not that relevant in the code you provided, maybe it is used in other parts of your code base when a `json` specific output format is required. You can read more on `json` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) to know that it is a format independent of the python programming language.

Comment: This may be obvious, but since I'm relatively new to Python it took me a minute, so just for learning purposes: often keys/values are not both strings and so can't be concatenated, in which case I used  `s += str(x)`

Comment: Added description in my answer that hopefully helps to clarify the issue.