# Append string to new list if it doesn't include certain words

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, any

```
bad_words = ['Hi', 'hello', 'cool']
new_strings = []
for string in old_strings:
    if bad_words not in old_strings:
        new_strings.append(string)
```

how do I iterate through bad_words so that it doesnt include the strings that have them in it?

Comment: What do you mean? Needs more clarify/examples.

Comment: Change order in if statement `if string not in bad_words:`

Comment: @frigolit_tarzan, I added an answer that might be an alternative solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `any()` with a list comprehension:

```
bad_words = ['Hi', 'hello', 'cool']
new_strings = [string 
               for string in old_strings 
               if not any(bad_word in string for bad_word in bad_words)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bad_words = ['Hi', 'hello', 'cool']
new_strings = []
for string in old_strings:
    if string not in bad_words: 
        new_strings.append(string)
```

you question is not clear but i think this is the answer based on some assumptions

Comment: I guess it's the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong data structure. If you want unique values in a collection you should use a `set` instead of a list.

```py
bad_words = {'Hi', 'hello', 'cool'} # this is a set

# now if you want to add words to this set, call the update method
new_strings = []
bad_words.update(new_strings)
```

You can always convert a set into a string as follows:

```py
bad_words = {'Hi', 'hello', 'cool'}
l = list(bad_words)
```

For more information when to use a set/list/dict check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set/56997418#56997418).