# How to generate a dictionary with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have difficulties to generate a dictionary that contains identical keys. The actual code:

```
source = []
key = []
for foto in fotos.split(','):
    source.append(str(foto))
    key.append("source")
dictA = dict(zip(key, source))
pprint(dictA)
```

The output:

```
{'source': 'https://www.example.com/fma600/9364f794ed4e5cfc3ba9416ef4ebe065.jpg'}
```

But I need this dict output:

```
"pictures":[
  {"source":"http://yourServer/path/to/your/picture.jpg"},
  {"source":"http://yourServer/path/to/your/otherPicture.gif"},
  {"source":"http://yourServer/path/to/your/anotherPicture.png"}
 ]
```

The problem is: the API needs to duplicate pictures using the same key `"source"`. When I use `dict`, its not possible to duplicate and create another key with the same name.

Comment: Your desired output is a `list` of `dict`s, not a single `dict`.

Comment: `dict`s cannot have duplicate keys in Python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use a **list** containing **dict**.

Reference URL: [In Python, when to use a Dictionary, List or Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489100/11910438)

Please see following code.

```py
dictA = []
for foto in fotos.split(','):
    dictA.append({
        'source':str(foto),
    })
print(dictA)
```

Comment: Please provide a little explanation; code-only answers, even when correct, don't do much to help the OP figure out what they did wrong.

Answer (score -1):

For this specific case, unfortunatly python does not accept duplicate keys for dictionaries.. A possible workaround for the given problem, is to instead using dictionary, try using lists.

For example: `listA = list(zip(key, source))`

So the output should be something like:

```
"pictures":[
    ["source", "http://yourServer/path/to/your/picture.jpg"],
    ["source", "http://yourServer/path/to/your/otherPicture.gif"],
    ["source", "http://yourServer/path/to/your/anotherPicture.png"]
]
```

Those strings could be easily accessed by using the index `[0]` for the source string, and `[1]` for the link string.