# how to assign variables in another variable in python?

Tags: python

I need to have different results for different "i"s
so whenever i call for example a_8, it should return me the exact value. but python
doesnt assign diferrent "i"s to it and just knows a_i.

1.`for i in range(10): a_i = i + 5`

Comment: Look up dictionaries in python.

Comment: Just use an array with indicies

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array):

```python
a = []
for i in range(10): a.append(i+5)
```

or a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array):

```python
a = {}
for i in range(10): a[i] = i+5
```

In both cases, you can access the value later with

```
for i in range(10): print(a[i])
```

**What I should use on my case?**
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489100/11103856).

Comment: in this case the index of list is equal to the value of i, what if it was not like this or what if we had 2 variable i and j

Answer (score 0):

for i in range(10):
globals()['a_' + str(i)] = i + 5
print(a_6)

but i don't think you should use it, better use dicts instead.