# Ansible: Select one specific item value from a list

Tags: ansible

I have a list:

```yaml
awx_credentials:
  - name: "user1"
    password: "123"
  - name: "user2"
    password: "123"
  - name: "user3"
    password: "123"
  - name: "user4"
    password: "123"
```

In one task I need to get the name of the `user2` name like this:

```yaml
- name: "My test"
  awx.awx.execution_environment:
  name: "My EE"
  image: "quay.io/ansible"
  credential: "{{ awx_credentials[1].name }}"
```

But if I change the order of the list, this will not work.

How could I get the value of `name` searching for `user2` into the list?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: => `{{ awx_credentials | selectattr('name', '==', 'user2') | map(attribute='name') | first  }}` but this is an overkill as the result is the same thing as hardcoding `"user2"` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data for testing

```yaml
  awx_credentials:
    - {name: user1, password: A}
    - {name: user2, password: B}
    - {name: user3, password: C}
    - {name: user4, password: D}
```

---

This is a typical case of wrong data structure. In the list *awx_credentials*, the values of the attribute *name* are unique. A better data structure is a dictionary. If you have to use the list convert it to a dictionary first

```yaml
  awx_credentials_dict: "{{ awx_credentials|
                            items2dict(key_name='name',
                                       value_name='password') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  awx_credentials_dict:
    user1: A
    user2: B
    user3: C
    user4: D
```

Then, looking for the passwords is trivial.

See: [In Python, when to use a Dictionary, List or Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to search dynamically for usernames and mostly like to get the password since the username is already given.

A minimal example playbook which will lookup the password for a given user.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    credentials:
    - name: "user1"
      password: "pwd1"
    - name: "user2"
      password: "pwd2"
    - name: "user3"
      password: "pwd3"
    - name: "user4"
      password: "pwd4"

    USER: "user2"

  tasks:

  - name: My test
    debug:
      msg: "{{ credentials[1].password }}"

  - name: Other test
    debug:
      msg: "{{ credentials | selectattr('name', '==', USER) | map(attribute='password') | first }}"
```

<sub>*... and based on the comment of Zeitounator*</sub>

The variable for the user could even be

```yaml
{{ credentials | selectattr('name', '==', ansible_user) | map(attribute='password') | first }}
```

to make automation and execution easier.

**Further Documentation**

- [Manipulating data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)