# c++: search vector of base class pointers

Tags: c++, python, class, hash

I'm trying to create something like an analogue for Python's `list`. There are some objects derived from class `Object`. There is also class `List`, which is just a overlay for `std::vector<Object*>`. All classes have `clone` function (as well as some other functions). Now I'm trying to provide a possibility to find an index for the given element (like Python's `list.index`). It would be also great to provide a possibility to sort in future, i.e. to compare objects inside `List` class. How can I realise it without having to overload `operator==`? I've heard about hashing algorithms. Is it the thing that I'm looking for? If yes, could you advice a library or (better) how can I implement it using raw C++?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking which c++ container is best to use? If so, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010097/general-use-cases-for-c-containers.

Comment: why can't you overload `operator==`?

Comment: Python is my favorite language, but what you're trying to do sounds like a horrible idea to me.