# Appropiate std container for (only) insertion and iteration

Tags: c++, containers, std

Which will be the std container to use if I only want to insert a lot (10.000-100.000) of small (int,floats and doubles) items and then iterate over all of them (order is not important)? (Note: the number of items is unknown at the start)

I have noticed that unsorted_set, list and forward_list have O(1) for insertion and O(n) for iteration. Is there any other which also has that complexity? Which one of those is the fastest? (if there is significant differences in memory use i will also be interested in knowing about them.

(I'm only interested in std containers, not Boost or other libraries ones)

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010097/general-use-cases-for-c-containers

Comment: Define 'a lot', also how big are they? The answer is likely to be `vector`.

Comment: It depends heavily on the number of elements you want to hold, their type, and the patterns of access. You should profile it in a realistic running scenario. `std::vector` is a likely candidate for the best fit.

Comment: Question has been edited to reflect size and number of items

Comment: Post-edit, answer is almost definitely `std::vector` on a 'normal' machine. You could happily `.reserve(200000)` on a `vector<double>` and reduce the number of allocations to one without stressing a modern (in the loosest possible sense) machine.

Comment: If you know the maximum size then vector will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is `std::vector` with a call to `std::vector::reserve()`.

Answer (score 0):

vector might be a good choice. It is same as array in memory consumption. O(1) insertion(If you are inserting at the end) and O(n) iteration. It's simplest of containers and is a good choice if deletion or random insertion is not on your list.

Comment: std::vector would have a lot of reallocs that wouldn't be neccesary in a forward_list for example. Also it is not the same as array in memory consumption

Comment: @Trollkemada A vector is much closer to an array's memory consumption than any kind of linked list. In fact, it's virtually identical (about two pointers larger *in total*) when the vector is sized correctly. Also, with 100k elements and even assuming you don't pre-size the vector, there would only be about 17 re-allocs, most of which only copy a few dozen or hundred items.

Comment: After looking at all the others comments in all the answers, seems like vector is the best

Answer (score 0):

All of the classes in your question have optimal complexity for what you want, but std::vector may be faster, *in particular* if you know how many elements you want to insert approximately, i.e. you have an upper bound available.

I suppose that performance may differ depending on your compiler, compiler version and the number of elements you want to insert. Sorry for not providing more specific help.

Comment: `std::vector` may be faster even if you don't have an upper bound on the number of elements. You just have to measure this stuff.

Comment: std::vector would have to do a lot of reallocs if we do not know the number of items, right?

Comment: @Trollkemada Correct, but the number of reallocs may not be that bad either. For example if you increase (reserved) container size exponentially there are only a couple of reallocs. If you iterate a lot over the container, this may pay off.

Comment: I think std::vector is the best bet if you are able to do a std::vector.reserve to prevent reallocation

Comment: @Trollkemada it will have to do some, but it might be blindingly quick to do so compared to, say, traversing a list to find a point of insertion. The speed of iteration will be considerably faster, and it will have better cache behaviour.

Comment: @Trollkemada Again, only about `log_a n` where `a` is the resizing factor (commonly between 1.5 and 4). And the cache friendliness will most likely outweigh that.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to me it depends on what you want to do with the elements in the container.

- If you want to insert elements at some positions, then list is the fastest because arrays and vectors have to move all the items after the insert position, one step forward.
- On the other hand, if you want to access an item at a position, then arrays and vectors are faster.

Moreover, other than these there are container adapters as well like queue, stack, priority_queue etc.

So again, it all depends on your implementation and what you want from the container of elements.

Comment: As I said in the question, order is not important so I am not interested in inserting at any position, just insert (in any position) and then iterate over all the elements (in whatever order) so i am not interested in access an item in a given position

Comment: std::vector seems the best fit in that case