# Can I erase a node in the middle of a std::queue?

Tags: c++, containers

If I have a `std:queue` can I erase an element in the middle?

Or should I just go for a simple vector?

EDIT:

In the end, my search became between `std::list` and `std::deque`. [this post](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/09/11/choosing-the-right-container-sequential-containers/) gives a nice comparison, although I am still a bit undecided.

On one side, since after deletion I won't be accessing more members (the operation finishes) I am not that concerned about iterator invalidation. 
On the other side, I will probably access (or search) elements one by one, so random access might not be that important...

Comment: Related and/or interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010097/general-use-cases-for-c-containers

Answer (score 5):

1. No, not unless you want to take all the elements out and put them back in again.
2. A `std::list` might be better, but it depends on what else you want to do with it.

Comment: I want to do the common operations of a queue plus deleting middle elements on occasion (would require finding said element). I heard deque's might be of help. What do you think?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010097/general-use-cases-for-c-containers which contains a handy flowchart of what containers might fit your needs

Comment: @Tas Thanks. I did that and I got `std::list`. So now I am between list, vector or deque...:)

Comment: vectors are good for stacks but not queues, vector only allows efficient addition/removal at the back but a queue needs to remove elements at the opposite end from where they are inserted. deque and list are both good for queues. And depending on the object type there are also the equivalent types in boost.intrusive.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir That is great advice! So in my case vectors should be out. Now my options are between `std::list` and `std:deque`... To delete a member in the middle I have first to find it, so some simple search is also needed

Comment: @KansaiRobot in most common cases `std::deque` will perform better than `std::list`.

Answer (score 4):

`std:: queue` is a container adapter i.e. it processes elements in a specific order 'First in First Out'. Why would you want to break this order? First, you can't erase elements from any position of an `std:: queue` except `front` end (Until and unless you use another auxiliary data structure). If you want a similar functionality then even before an `std:: list` go blindly for an `std:: vector`. Profile your code and if you feel the need of `std:: list` go for it.

Comment: Understood your point,Thanks!. I have been just told that vector allows efficient removal at the back so they are not that convenient for my needs. I am now between lists and deques.

Comment: @KansaiRobot You should go with `deque` then, `deque` has proven to be flexible and easier to use in my experience. Can't say much though.

Comment: @KansaiRobot `std::deque` give a nice balance between FIFO (First In, First Out) and random access. If you need both, `std::deque` is definitely the way to go.