# Dynamically allocated list in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dangling-pointer

I made a cute generic (i.e. template) `List` class to handle lists in C++. The reason for that is that I found the `std::list` class terribly ugly for everyday use and since I constantly use lists, I needed a new one. The major improvement is that with my class, I can use `[]` to get items from it. Also, still to be implemented is an `IComparer` system to sort things.

I'm using this `List` class in `OBJLoader`, my class that loads Wavefront .obj files and converts them to meshes. `OBJLoader` contains lists of pointers to the following "types": 3D positions, 3D normals, uv texture coordinates, vertices, faces and meshes. The vertices list has objects that must be linked to some objects in all of the 3D positions, 3D normals and uv texture coordinates lists. Faces link to vertices and meshes link to faces. So they are all inter-connected.

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider that, in some context, there are just two lists of pointers: `List<Person*>` and `List<Place*>`. `Person` class contains, among others, the field `List<Place*> placesVisited` and the `Place` class contains the field `List<Person*> peopleThatVisited`. So we have the structure:

```
class Person
{
    ...
  public:
    Place* placeVisited;
    ...
};

class Place
{
    ...
  public:
    List<People*> peopleThatVisited;
};
```

Now we have the following code:

```
Person* psn1 = new Person();
Person* psn2 = new Person();

Place* plc1 = new Place();
Place* plc2 = new Place();
Place* plc2 = new Place();


// make some links between them here:
psn1->placesVisited.Add(plc1, plc2);
psn2->placesVisited.Add(plc2, plc3);

// add the links to the places as well
plc1->peopleThatVisited.Add(psn1);
plc2->peopleThatVisited.Add(psn1, psn2);
plc3->peopleThatVisited.Add(plc3);

// to make things worse:

List<Person*> allThePeopleAvailable;

allThePeopleAvailable.Add(psn1);
allThePeopleAvailable.Add(psn2);

List<Place*> allThePlacesAvailable;

allThePlacesAvailable.Add(plc1);
allThePlacesAvailable.Add(plc2);
allThePlacesAvailable.Add(plc3);
```

All done. What happens when we reach `}`? All the dtors are called and the program crashes because it tries to delete things two or more times.

The dtor of my list looks like this:

```
~List(void)
{
    cursor = begin;
    cursorPos = 0;

    while(cursorPos &#60; capacity - 1)
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
        cursorPos++;
        delete cursor->prev;
    }

    delete cursor;
}
```

where `Elem` is:

```
struct Elem
{
  public:
    Elem* prev;
    T value;
    Elem* next;
};
```

and `T` is the generic `List` type.

Which brings us back to the question: What ways are there to safely delete my `List` classes? The elements inside may or may not be pointers and, if they are pointers, I would like to be able, when I delete my `List`, to specify whether I want to delete the elements inside or just the `Elem` wrappers around them.

Smart pointers could be an answer, but that would mean that I can't have a `List<bubuType*>`, but just `List<smart_pointer_to_bubuType>`. This could be ok, but again: declaring a `List<bubuType*>` would cause no error or warning and in some cases the smart pointers would cause some problems in the implementation: for example, I might want to declare a `List<PSTR>` for some WinAPI returns. I think getting those `PSTR` inside smart pointers would be an ugly job. Thus, the solution I'm looking for I think should be somehow related to the deallocation system of the `List` template.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say indexed access to a linked list is somewhat more "not pretty" than std::list. Sure you don't want std::vector?

Comment: I wonder why people don't use `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Comment: Best advice that I can give you (without having completed the reading of the question) is that you should learn the C++ idioms. The STL library is very well designed, and you can learn much from understanding it. Also, implementing indexing into a list is probably not a good idea in itself, if you need indexing, use a vector rather than a list. Random access into a list takes linear time, and I bet that at the end you just write loops that iterate sequentially over the elements...

Comment: @Erik: the thing is I need a dynamic container for certain uses and I thought that a list was the best. Nevertheless, it's a little bit inconvenient to use the std::list when you want access to those elements. "(*&*)iterator" is kinda strange for me. My reference was the C# list.

Comment: @cantrem: The C# list is a `std::vector`, not a `std::list`.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to use vectors: they reallocate all the stuff when the current capacity is exceeded and inserting/deleting elements is more time-expensive. Random access into a list takes liniar time, yes, but if you rarely use it for getting things from random locations and you usually go through it from 0 to count - 1, the extra time to move the cursor ain't all that bad.

Comment: @cantrem: would you use a List, or an ArrayList? What operations do you want to use in the container? Do you really need random access or will you use sequential only access?

Comment: C++ is not C#. Each language has it's own way of doing things and you should modify your programming approach so that it works with the language you're using.

Comment: @cantrem: If you want to *learn* how to write a linked list, by all means go ahead, every programmer should do that at least once. If you want, as a new C++ user, to replace thoroughly tested and optimized class templates written by experienced c++ programmers and known to more or less every c++ programmer, then I think you're on the wrong track.

Comment: @cantrem: How do you want to iterate from `0` to `count-1`? Because if you implement it as: `for ( int i = 0; i < count; ++i ) { l[i].op(); }` then the iteration over the list takes O(n^2) time, not linear.

Comment: @cantrem: As a sequential container, `std::vector` should be your first choice, and [will often be what you end up with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056973/when-do-you-prefer-using-stdlistt-instead-of-stdvectort/5057001#5057001), because it's faster.

Comment: @Erik: :) beware, once you understand the STL, and in particular iterators, you will write a *better* list. (*Disclaimer: better as in better than you would write *before* understanding STL, not as in better than the one implemented in the STL)

Comment: @ David Rodríguez: incorrect, the iterator is moved each time one position to the right (in my implementation)

Comment: ok, it seems I have opened Pandora's box with my List implementation; i was totally wrong to try to implement a new container class since stl has all I need, so I'll switch to the std::vector; the main question still remains: what ways are there to safely delete my lists/vectors? The elements inside may or may not be pointers and, if they are pointers, I would like to be able, when I delete my lists/vectors, to specify whether I want to delete the actual allocated objects or just the pointers to them

Comment: Use the appropriate standard container.

Comment: After looking at all the answers I can tell you they're all partially right. 1) you're error comes from not having one container clearly own each item, so you end up with multiple deletes 2) you shouldn't re-implement list, use stl::list 3) if you want direct access, dynamic sizing and the ability to just append to the end use stl::vector

Comment: @cantrem: While we pretend to abhor your idea, secretly we're all craving for someone to open Pandora's box once in a while, because it's always such a fun spectacle. Anyway, you nicely countered this by taking it sportsmanlike and adjusting your POV. by now you already have at least two good answers to your actual question, David's and DeadMG's, both of which have my vote, since I agree with them.

Comment: @sbi: well I just think that asking questions without hearing answers is kinda pointless

Comment: @cantrem: That seems like an attitude that might get you far in life. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer is that you must think on the lifetime of each one of the objects, and the responsibility of managing that lifetime.

In particular, in a relation from people and the sites they have visited, most probably neither of them should be naturally made responsible for the lifetime of the others: people can live independently from the sites that they have visited, and places exists regardless of whether they have been visited. This seems to hint that the lifetime of both people and sites is unrelated to the others, and that the pointers held are not related to resource management, but are rather *references* (not in the C++ sense).

Once you know who is responsible for managing the resource, that should be the code that should `delete` (or better hold the resource in a container or suitable smart pointer if it needs to be dynamically allocated), and you must ensure that the deletion does not happen before the other objects that refer to the same elements finish with them.

If at the end of the day, in your design ownership is not clear, you can fall back to using `shared_ptr` (either `boost` or `std`) being careful not to create circular dependencies that would produce memory leaks. Again to use the `shared_ptr`s correctly you have to go back and think, *think on the lifetime of the objects...*

Comment: Indeed, there is also something wrong with the design. And often, problems like those above, indicate some kind of design error. To my knowledge, I've never used smart or auto pointers in my design (because, as you say, every object has one and only one owner).

Comment: Extrapolating to the real .obj loader problem: if I understand correctly, I should pass all my lists out of the loader's scope (since the loader shouldn't actually delete anything, just transform some data and pass it along - and this was actually the thing I was going for, but when I first compiled my code to check for errors, I bumped into this one and I thought it would be better to learn about the causes and solutions in general contexts). And, when I start freeing memory, I should make sure that each destructor only breaks the references between the objects.

Answer (score 11):

Without even looking at your code, I say: scrap it!

C++ has a list class template that's about as ***efficient*** as it gets, ***well-known*** to all C++ programmers, and comes ***bug-free*** with your compiler.

***Learn to use the STL.***<sup>1</sup> Coming from other OO languages, the STL might seem strange, but there's an underlying reason for its strangeness, an alien beauty ***combining abstraction and performance*** - something considered impossible before Stepanov came and thought up the STL.
Rest assured that you are not the only one struggling with understanding the STL. When it came upon us, we all struggled to grasp its concepts, to learn its particularities, to understand how it ticks. The STL *is* a strange beast, but then it manages to combine two goals everybody thought could never be combined, so it's allowed to seem unfamiliar at first.

I bet writing your own linked list class used to be the second most popular indoor sport of C++ programmers - right after writing your own string class. Those of us who had been programming C++ 15 years ago nowadays enjoy ripping out those bug-ridden, inefficient, strange, and unknown string, list, and dictionary classes rotting in old code, and replacing it with something that is very ***efficient***, ***well-known***, and ***bug-free***. Starting your own list class (other than for educational purposes) has to be one of the worst heresies.

If you program in C++, get used to one of the mightiest tools in its box as soon as possible.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that the term "STL" names that part of the C++ standard library that stems from Stepanov's library (plus things like `std::string` which got an STL interface attached as an afterthought), not the whole standard library.</sub>

Comment: +1 writing your own list as an exercise is one thing. Writing it to use in production code is another (especially implementing operator[] which can't operate in constant time on a list).

Comment: ~ +1 (~ meaning that I will not upvote :P), while I agree with everything stated here, I don't think this is actually related with the question, which is about handling object lifetimes, rather than the choice of implementing his own container. The same problem would arise if he was using `std::list< type* >` (or `std::vector<type*>`)

Comment: @David: As I said, I haven't even looked closely at the question. There's numerous question about object lifetime management in C++, and if this one would indeed be missing, it would be answered quickly and pointedly if asked about `std::list<type*>`. But writing your own list class (not for education, but because you disagree with the std lib) warrants only one answer: don't.

Answer (score 3):

Always, *always* use smart pointers if you are responsible for deallocating that memory. Do not ever use raw pointers unless you *know* that you're not responsible for deleting that memory. For WinAPI returns, wrap them into smart pointers. Of course, a list of raw pointers is not an error, because you may wish to have a list of objects whose memory you do not own. But avoiding smart pointers is most assuredly not a solution to any problem, because they're a completely essential tool.

And just use the Standard list. That's what it's for.

Comment: Easier said than done, the problem keeps being deciding on who has ownership. Because persons hold references to places and places to people, any naïve approach (think `shared_ptr`) will fail. Smart pointers don't allow you to just turn the brain off and get everything working, they just help avoiding errors *after* thinking.

Comment: @David: Of course. But you have to think about ownership anyway- there's no avoiding it.

Answer (score 1):

In the lines:
// make some links between them here:
psn1->placesVisited.Add(plc1, plc2);
psn2->placesVisited.Add(plc2, plc3);

// add the links to the places as well
plc1->peopleThatVisited.Add(psn1);
plc2->peopleThatVisited.Add(psn1, psn2);
plc3->peopleThatVisited.Add(plc3);

---

You have instances on the heap that contain pointers to each others. Not only one, but adding the same Place pointer to more than one person will also cause the problem (deleting more than one time the same object in memory).

Telling you to learn STL or to use shared_ptr (Boost) can be a good advice, however, as David Rodríguez said, you need to think of the lifetime of the objects. In other words, you need to redesign this scenario so that the objects do not contain pointers to each other.

Example: Is it really necessary to use pointers? - in this case, and if you require STL lists or vectors, you need to use shared_ptr, but again, if the objects make reference to each other, not even the best shared_ptr implementation will make it.

If this relationship between places and persons is required, design a class or use a container that will carry the references to each other instead of having the persons and places point at each other. Like a many-to-many table in a RDBMS. Then you will have a class/container that will take care of deleting the pointers at the end of the process. This way, no relations between Places and Persons will exist, only in the container.

Regards, J. Rivero

Answer (score 0):

Without looking the exact code of the Add function, and the destructor of your list, it's hard to pin point the problem.

However, as said in the comments, the main problem with this code is that you don't use `std::list` or `std::vector`. There are proven efficient implementations, which fit what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would certainly use the STL (standard template library), but, I see that you are learning C++, so as an exercise it can be nice to write such a thing as a List template.

First of all, you should never expose data members (e.g. `placeVisited` and `peopleThatVisited`). This is a golden rule in object oriented programming. You should use getter and setter methods for that.

Regarding the problem around double deletion: the only solution is having a wrapper class around your pointers, that keeps track of outstanding references. Have a look at the [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). ([Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is another magnificent well-crafted C++ library).

Comment: Naïvely using `shared_ptr` will leak memory. The code contains circular references, in particular each person is bound to a place that contains a back reference to the person.

Comment: I know, I know, I only used it in the example so that I wouldn't have to write getters & setters for them. About the shared pointers: apparently it isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

The program crashes because delete deallocates the memory of the pointer it is given it isn't removing the items from you list. You have the same pointer in at least two lists, so delete is getting called on the same block of memory multiple times this causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

First, smart pointers are not the answer here.  All they will do is
guarantee that the objects never get deleted (since a double linked list
contains cycles, by definition).

Second, there's no way you can pass an argument to the destructor
telling it to delete contained pointers: this would have to be done
either via the list's type, one of its template arguments, partial
specialization or an argument to the constructor.  (The latter would
probably require partial specialization as well, to avoid trying to
delete a non-pointer.)

Finally, the way to not delete an object twice is to not call delete on
it twice.  I'm not quite sure what you thing is happening in your
destructor, but you never change cursor, so every time through, you're
deleting the same two elements.  You probably need something more along
the lines of:

```
while ( cursor not at end ) {
    Elem* next = cursor->next;
    delete cursor;
    cursor = next;
}
```

-- 
James Kanze

Comment: actually the destructor works fine, please read the code inside it again.

Answer (score -1):

And you could easily implement [] around a normal list:

```
template <class Type> 
class mystdlist : public std::list<Type> { 
public: 
    Type& operator[](int index) { 
       list<Type>::iterator iter = this.begin(); 

       for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++ ) { 
          iter++; 
       }
       return *iter; 
    }  
};
```

Why you would want to do this is strange, IMHO.  If you want O(1) access, use a vector.

Comment: O(n^2) time for traversing the list from 0 to count-1

Comment: AARGH! Never, **EVER**, derive publicly from a class that does not have a virtual destructor. The safer alternative is definitely composition + forwarding functions. Deriving privately + bringing in stuff via `using` is the best compromise.

Comment: @Cantrem: I never said it would be fast.  :-)  @Matthieu, thanks for the tip

Comment: "O(n^2) time for traversing the list from 0 to count-1 " -> that's the reason for not deriving from std::list like you pointed out

Comment: @Cantrem:  My point was that the OP had a list with array [] semantics.  I don't think I was implying that it would be O(1).  Whether deriving from std::list or not, he's going to end up with O(n^2).  Unless his list really isn't a list.