# Vector vs list according to Stroustrup

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you prefer using std::list<T> instead of std::vector<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056973/when-do-you-prefer-using-stdlistt-instead-of-stdvectort)

I just watched the recording of the GoingNative'12 talk by Bjarne Stroustrup. And I'm a bit confused.

In this talk he in particular discusses the `vector` vs `list` question and suggest that in many cases `vector` is faster even if you insert and remove intensively to/from the middle, as compilers can optimize a lot of things and like compact structures. And the conclusion(as I understand it) is: first use `vector` and later think whether you need something else. That sounds reasonable, but taking into account the first observation, what criteria I should take into account? I always thought that if you insert/remove intensively - use list. Similar things are suggested in some topics here. See

[Relative performance of std::vector vs. std::list vs. std::slist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238008/relative-performance-of-stdvector-vs-stdlist-vs-stdslist)

and

[vector vs. list in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl)

And now according to Stroustrup I was wrong.

Of course I can write a couple of tests and try to figure out what to use in each particular situation, but is there a theoretical way?

Comment: Actually, if `vector` is slow you should next try `deque` before `list`.

Comment: +1 to Pubby. Unless I *need* continuity for all elements in the sequence (i.e. a big-ass buffer) I prefer deque anyway, which frankly has one of the slickest management algorithms in the entire std lib.

Comment: Use a profiler to compare both versions with production data, then choose the one that performs better.

Comment: @WhozCraig Except that `deque` doesn't generally improve performance in such cases.  In practice, the only reason I've found to use anything other than `std::vector` is iterator safety, and `std::deque` doesn't help there; you need `std::list`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most important motivation for preferring `std::list` over `std::vector` is the validity of iterators, *not* performance.  If at the time you're inserting or erasing, you have other iterators into the container, then you probably need `std::list`, since it insertion doesn't invalidate any iterators, and erasure only invalidates iterators to the element being erased.  About the only time `std::list` will win on performance is when copy and assignment are extremely expensive, and in such cases, it's often a better choice to modify the contained class to reduce the cost of copy and assignment, rather than switching to `std::list`.

Comment: If you just need stable iterators, you should consider something like [boost::container::stable_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/container/stable_vector.html).

Comment: @Mankarse if you're not already making use of boost, adding boost dependencies to a project to get stable iterators seems a little excessive, given that you could just use `std::list`.