# hash_map,map hash function for composite key

Tags: c++, stl, cstring

I got a working std::map class, which is somewhat slow, so I want to try other datastructures

My key is a composite datatype like

```
typedef struct {
  char * name;
  int offset;
}position;
```

And for the std::map I'm using the following partial ordering function

```
struct cmp_position {
  bool operator()(const position& first,const  position& second) {
    int tmp = std::strcmp(first.name, second.name);
    if(tmp!=0)
      return tmp<0;
    else
      return first.offset<second.offset;
  }
};
```

And my map definition is

```
typedef std::map<position,int,cmp_position> myMap;
```

I've been looking at the __gcc_ext::hash_map this requires an equality function which could simply be

```
struct positionEq
{
  bool operator()(const position& s1, const position & s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1.name, s2.name) == 0 && (s1.offset==s2.offset) ;
  }
};
```

Which should work, but I'm having troubles with the hash function of my composite type.
I guess I could do something like

```
position s;
char buf[100];
snprintf(buf,100,"%s:%d\n",s.name,s.offset);
```

But I'm having problems glueing it together.

Actually the map and hash map might be somewhat overkill since I'm not using the value of the keys, I'm solely using my map for checking for existence.

It's my intention not to use std::strings.

Thanks

Edit:

In the above example, I tried with a std::set instead of std::map, and std::set is consistently slower both populating and looking up entries. It uses a lot less memory though the overall comparison is tabulated below. I tried running each 10 times

```
         Set        map
 size   1.8gig     3.1gig
 pop    <15sec     <14sec
 find   <12sec     <9sec
```

I used a dataset with more than 34mio entries, and after populating the datastructure, i tried looking up all 34 mio elements. I guess the conclusion is, that other than apart from conserving memory, the std::set is inferior.

Comment: Please define "is somewhat slow". What is slow? Insertion? Finding? Traversal?

Comment: It's better to learn unordered_map than hash_map. Both are hash tables, but unordered_map is (or very soon will be) standard.

Comment: If you don't need values, use `set/hash_set/unordered_set`

Comment: It should be _somewhat fast_ in a release build, how are you profiling to determine this? In agreement with Steve, if you don't need values use a more appropriate container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with the key structure storing a hashed value of `name` (using `boost::hash_value` for example) - so that comparing key objects would be just two number comparisons, which should be pretty quick.

Try testing it with an `unordered_set`.  The [`boost::multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) claims to outperform `std::set` and such in some circumstances, you could see if that speeds things along a bit (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389481/c-cache-design-advice/6393065#6393065) for an example of its use).