# Are there any Sorted Collections in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, stl, adt

In Smalltalk, you can create a sortedCollection, which is to say that you can add an element and it would insert it into the correct location.

Is there anything like this in C++?  Or even better is there anything like a sortedQueue, such that when you add an element, it would sort it into a queue like structure that you can just pop the first element off of?

I looked into set, this is what I need in terms of sorting, but it is an unordered collection.  I am looking for a small run time as possible.

Comment: "*I looked into set, this is what I need in terms of sorting, but it is an unordered collection*" Huh? `set` is ordered, `unordered_set` isn't.

Comment: You are wrong, `std::set` is ordered.

Comment: `set` is ordered, using `std::less` by default, so looping through `myset.begin()` to `myset.end()` will go through the elements in ascending order.

Comment: @ildjarn & @Fetissov I think I must have misread it then.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), which is located in the `<queue>` header file. With `push()`, you can insert an element into the priority queue; with `top()`, you will get the currently largest element in the queue (or the smallest one, depending on how you implement `operator<`); and with `pop()`, you will remove the largest/smallest element.

As far as I know, it's implemented with a heap, which makes the time complexity of each push and pop operation *O(lg n)*. Simply looking at the top element is done in *O(1)*.

Answer (score 59):

There are four sorted containers in the C++ standard library:

[`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) - A sorted sequence of unique values.
[`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) - A sorted sequence of unique key/value pairs.
[`std::multiset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/) - A sorted sequence of values (possible repeats).
[`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) - A sorted sequence of key/value pairs (possible repeats).

If you just want a sorted queue, then what you are looking for is [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/), which is a *container adaptor* rather than a stand-alone container.

```
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int> q;
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);
    q.push(1);
    assert(q.top() == 3); q.pop();
    assert(q.top() == 2); q.pop();
    assert(q.top() == 1); q.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to store your own types in a `priority_queue` then you need to define `operator<` for your class.

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(int age) : m_age(age) {}

    bool operator<(const Person& other) const
    {
        return m_age < other.m_age;
    }

private:
    int m_age;
};
```

Creating a `priority_queue` of `Person`s would then give you a queue with the oldest people at the front.

Answer (score 55):

The STL container choice flowchart (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container) question):

[image]

Comment: Even looking at this diagram I can't say what would be the best one to use in my quastion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329011/mfc-dictionary-collection-with-key-unicity-and-ordering-by-position

Comment: Great chart! but link became broken. Anyway here is updated version for C++11:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22671607/3052438

Answer (score 7):

[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) for sorted container

[std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/queue/) for queue.

[std::priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/) for sorted queue

Comment: Hmmm, I dont think map is what I am looking for.  I might as well just use set, but there is nothing where they combine them into one adt?

Comment: @Jim - what is it that you need? *sortedQueue* as you described is `std::priority_queue`. I mentioned `map` because you asked for a general sorted container (at least that is what I understood from your discussion of *sortedCollection*).

Comment: I think priority queue is exactly what I need, thanks. I dont think it was there when I made that comment.

Comment: std::set for sorted container. Map is pair were the data is sorted by a separate key.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` is an ordered collection; iterating over it will give you the elements in order (either as defined by the `<` operator or a custom predicate). Finding and removing the first element are O(1).

Alternatively you could use `std::priority_queue`, which is basically a heap and allows efficient insert and least item removal.

In fact it's harder to find unordered (hashed) containers - they weren't part of the original standard, although they were widely available in non-standard form.

Of course you may find that simply holding your items in a sorted vector is faster, even if it is theoretically slower, if the number of items is not significantly large.