# Container with constant time for accessing any element, pop from front and push back?

Tags: c++, containers, std

I'm looking for standard container (if any exists) that will have constant time for:

- access any element by position
- pop element from the front
- push element at back

I can program it by myself, but why bother if it could already exist in `std`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In which scenario do I use a particular STL Container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

Comment: I haven't seen it before, but it's abstract question compared to mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[std::deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/) is your friend. It's a double-ended queue with random access to elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a **[std::deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/)**. It satisfy's all your requirements.

- access any element by position

It provides random access using random iterators, as well as `operator []`

- pop element from the front

It provides **[pop_front()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/pop_front/)**

- push element at back

It provides **[push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/push_back/)**