# Insertion into sorted vector

Tags: c++

How does one insert an element into a sorted vector such that after the insertion the vector is still sorted?

```
std::vector<int> myVec {1, 1, 3, 6, 9};

sortedInsert(myVec, 4);

for(auto& out : myVec) std::cout << out << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

/*
* Expected output: 
* 1 1 3 4 6 9
*/
```

Comment: There are already questions and answers on exactly this topic, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048466); though your question and (self-)answer is a bit more  concise, I'll give you that...

Comment: @codeling imho it doesnt hurt to have duplicates around. I am just not sure which one to close as dupe of which ;)

Comment: well the second link from codeling is very close to this one. I am closing this one as duplicate. Not because I think this is a poor question or answer!

Comment: yeah I also don't feel too strongly about dupes; I posted the links mainly for reference, didn't vote to close (yet?); but this question here feels a bit like a "set up" to get points, with it's immediate *self-answer*

Comment: @codeling writing questions/answers to get points isnt something bad, is it ? ;)

Comment: If you have many insertions/removals switching to `std::set` instead might be worth a consideration...

Comment: @Aconcagua `std::set` doesnt store duplicates.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number not in and of itself but getting them via duplicate questions to which there are already perfectly good answers somewhere else doesn't feel right to me ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I swear I'm not that annoying. I'm just blind. I guess having a duplicate Q/A is better than having to try and search through 10 year old questions with heaps of redundant answers.

Comment: @spitconsumer i am completely with you. Finding q/as is difficult sometimes and having another duplicate as entry point can be good, especially when it is well written

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ah, of course, should have been `std::multi_set` instead ;)

Comment: The [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector) would have been better duplicate – even better formatted answer...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<algorithm>` library function [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) to find where to insert the element.

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T, class Compare = std::less<>>
std::vector<T>::iterator sorted_insert(std::vector<T>& vec, const T& val, Compare comp = Compare{}) {
    return vec.insert(std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val, comp), val);
}
```

When doing a sorted insertion, the position at which you want to insert is just before an element that is greater than the value you want to insert. i.e:

```
std::vector<int> myVec { 1, 1, 3, 6, 9};
//                             ^
// A sorted insert on this vector with value = 2 would insert here
```

`std::upper_bound` returns an iterator to the first element in a sorted container that is greater than the value supplied, or, if there are no elements greater than the value supplied, `std::upper_bound` will return the end iterator of that sorted container.

Therefore, using a vector's `insert` method with the returned iterator from `std::upper_bound` will insert the supplied value such that the vector remains sorted post-insertion.

Comment: Worth to note: `std::lower_bound` would work as well, sorting new elements *in front of* equal ones instead of behind – which would be less efficient with `std::vector` (more elements to move towards end) but more with e.g. `std::list` (insertion location found earlier, no moving needed).