# What is the significance of Dynamic data structure(like linked list)

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, dynamic, linked-list

Once the program that created the linked list is closed without deleting the dynamic memory and I know that dynamic memory needs to be deleted then how can i get it back to work after reopening the program and if i can't get back the linked list then what is the use of linked list

Comment: What connection do you think linked lists have with persistence between multiple runs of a program?

Comment: You may want to look into serialization.

Comment: Dynamic memory is going to be deleted when the program terminates.
The purpose of a linked list is for instance in case where you don't know up front how many items you are going to need and hence a simple array would not work.

Comment: Sure it will. When the program terminates the OS is going to do the cleanup for you. But it is not considered good practice to rely on it.

Comment: @Ankit All modern operating systems free any memory a program failed to when it was terminated. It is best practice to clean up after yourself to prevent bugs and be certain other resources are cleaned up.

Comment: I'd add to @Sqeaky's comment that while it's not strictly necessary to free your heap memory before exiting, if you always code in ways which ensure that (like using appropriate smart-pointer classes), you're going to get fewer bugs like memory leaks when you extend the code later and end up with an exit point that's not in the same place it used to be.

Comment: @MatthewWalton Both of our comments also presume that it would be possible to know when the program will terminate. If we put our code in a library we would be completely at the mercy of the application author. Library always have to clean up after themselves otherwise they will have bugs that would ultimately make the libraries unpopular.

Comment: @Sqeaky good point, libraries MUST clean up, or provide ways to ensure that their memory gets released by their users if their users are responsible for ownership. C++11 unique_ptr and shared_ptr are rather useful for expressing that kind of contract.

Comment: @MatthewWalton Where C++11 is involved I completely agree. For libraries written in previous C++ versions do you which require shared ownership semantics do you see a better way to handle than than documenting the issue?

Comment: I don't think that a better way even exists prior to C++11. One of the big benefits you get about having these smart pointer classes in the standard library is a much more explicit way of speccing ownership in the API itself. Outside that, if you just return a pointer, the only way to tell someone if they're responsible for deleting it is to document that fact. And someone is bound to get it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you exit the program *everything* it has is gone. Including linked and unlinked lists, arrays, solo object and all.

If you want something to persist you must save it, then load it bask. Like in a text editor you use load and save.

There are full libraries to help the issue, you may start with [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) .

Comment: sure I do, but how that plays here? You should rephrase your question before it founders.

Comment: @Ankit at some level, deep inside, they use pointers. But that has nothing to do with this answer or your question.

Comment: @Ankit OK, in C the pointers are all exposed in the interface of a linked list. In C++ this doesn't have to be the case. So what?

Answer (score 1):

A linked list on its own has nothing to do with data persisting.

A linked list, when compared to other data structure has specific performance characteristics. It is unknown how long it might take to find a specific element, one might have to traverse the entire list(linear time), however insertions and deletions always take the same small fixed amount of time(constant time).

You might want to read about the STL containers as they have similar data structure inside them: [In which scenario do I use a particular STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

If you want data to persist beyond the running time of your application you research reading/writing to files, databases, network communication or whatever persistence mechanism might meet your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a linked list is that it's a flexible data structure for your code to use - it doesn't have a fixed length like an array, so you can add and remove items as much as you need to.

The reason people talk about dynamic memory allocation is because it's memory allocation which depends on the runtime behaviour of your program, which could change based on data which it reads. This is as opposed to static memory allocation, which is largely the same for a given code path for every run, and is much harder to work with for some problems. However, on some embedded systems it's your only option, and working within static memory allocation can also be faster in some cases (dynamic allocation tends to have a speed penalty associated with it).

The whole topic is quite complicated actually, and frequently gives me a headache.

Dynamically-allocated memory does not persist between runs of a program - the operating system cleans it all up when the program shuts down - so there is no relationship between dynamic memory allocation and data persistence. You have to use other mechanisms, usually storing on disc somewhere, for that. You can't get the memory back after the process has gone, that's the essence of the modern 'protected memory' model of multitasking where you can't access or even see memory which belongs to other processes. 'Other processes' includes subsequent runs of the same executable.