# Linked list with multiple data elements per key

Tags: c++, linked-list, element

I am creating an input manager, that stored events, and associated methods (`std::function<void()>`) to call when an event occurs. However, there may be multiple events to call when an event was fired. The obvious way of storing the event - function paring would be a `linked list`, but as there may be multiple functions this won't work. I'm thinking of just having a `linked list` which stores arrays of `std::function<void()>` as the elements. Is this an appropriate method to use, and if not what is the safest approach?

Comment: If it stores events and functions, why not a map? For multiple functions, a multimap.

Comment: @chris Thanks, sounds like what I want. I don't have much knowledge of what data structures are prebuilt into c++, so this is a great help!

Comment: @handuel, http://stackoverflow.com/a/471461/962089

Comment: @chris thanks once again. Bookmarked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your mapping of Event->Function in a `multimap`, which can store key/value combinations with duplicate keys.

```
std::multimap<Event, std::function<void()>> events_;
```

When an event is fired, you can find a list of all event handlers using `equal_range` which returns a `std::pair` of iterators of all the event handling functions. Call each of these to handle the event, e.g. (untested code)

```
void on_event(Event const &e) {
  for (auto r = events_.equal_range(e); r.first != r.second; ++r.first)
    r.first->second();
}
```

`equal_range` returns a pair of iterators, so loop between the two. On each iteration of the loop the iterator (r.first) points to a key/value pair. `r.first->first` will be `e` and `r.first->second` will be the function handler.

Comment: Thank you, fully answers the question, and thanks for showing me how to get all the event handlers.