# What is the fastest data structure (and sorting algorithm) to sort a set of numbers?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, vector, dictionary

I need a data structure which can hold a set of numbers and sort them as quick as possible.

I thought a list would be good because inserting a new number in to the list would be easier than a vector (which would require copying the elements after the insertion). However, traversing the linked list (I am using the sorted list as a lookup to grab objects from an unordered_map) is likely to be much slower because the memory is scattered throughout the heap.

I was thinking of using a map, but wouldn't this also have a bad memory access due to the non-continuous nature?

A statically-allocated array (with lots of empty space) and a fast sorting algorithm is another idea I thought upon.....

To recap- I need a data structure which allows me to insert new elements and re-sort the elements as quick as possible. The elements will be numbers.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/471432/819272) on how to choose your Standard Containers.

Comment: This is hard to answer since *fastest* depends not only on the big-O complexity, but also on the constant terms (i.e. a data structure with bad big-O might outperform a "better" one on "smaller" input sizes). Only a benchmark with realistic data can tell you what is "better" since "small" can often be pretty large.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest data structure is an array- contiguous regions of memory, optimal for the cache.

Sorting depends. A combination of quicksort with insertion sort used to sort sub-arrays below a certain size might be your best bet without resorting to something more esoteric.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to think about how you *store* these objects in your `vector`/`map`.  A smart pointer with the necessary comparison functor is probably what you want.

Comment: I am just storing primitives? All I want is a storage container to store sorted numbers and allow me to insert/iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

If by "set of numbers" you mean each number only occurs once, and you want it sorted, use std::set. To be honest, unless you are dealing with huge amounts of data, std::list or even std::vector will probably be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Boost.Containers**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) library contains a `flat_set` data structure. It implements a `std::set` interface on top of a `std::vector` data storage. Advantages according to the documentation

- Faster lookup than standard associative containers
- Much faster iteration than standard associative containers
- Less memory consumption for small objects (and for big objects if shrink_to_fit is used)
- Improved cache performance (data is stored in contiguous memory)
- Non-stable iterators (iterators are invalidated when inserting and erasing elements)
- Non-copyable and non-movable values types can't be stored
- Weaker exception safety than standard associative containers (copy/move constructors can throw when shifting values in erasures and insertions)
- Slower insertion and erasure than standard associative containers (specially for non-movable types)

Answer (score -1):

> What is the fastest data structure

An array.

> (and sorting algorithm)

Quicksort, provided you can tolerate the worst-case behaviour. Otherwise probably heapsort.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I think the question is unanswerable without more details (and e.g. even bogosort would outperform both algorithms you mention on certain inputs).