# What list class to use?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'd like to create a short lived list, over the life of a function, to collect a list of `CPoint` objects and then iterate over those objects. I'd like to use `CTypedPtrList` but I am not sure how to set it up to have it accept objects not derived from `CObject`; `CPoint` comes from a struct `tagPOINT`.

Is it possible to use `CTypedPtrList` with `CPoint`?

Otherwise, should I just use `std::list<CPoint>`? // I have started to use `std:list` and can successfully build a list, but I cannot find a way to iterate over the list.

```
std::list<CPoint*> pointList;
// Add to the list with list.push_front(new CPoint(x, y));
std::for_each(pointList.begin(), pointList.end(), [](pointList* cur)
{
    TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", cur->x, cur->y);
});
```

I have tried that, but I keep getting told that `for_each` is not a member of `std`. I tried to add `#include <for_each>` (as I had to do for `list`) but it still is not recognized.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try #include <algorithm>

Comment: The recommended default for lists is `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: `pointList` is not a type. Also, `for (auto cur : pointList) {/*use cur*/}`.

Comment: @FredOverflow vector **is not** for list.

Comment: @Cthulhu Care to elaborate?

Comment: Favor the stdlib containers over the MFC ones whenever possible. Your code will be more portable and better prepared for use with the different standard algorithms.

Comment: @FredOverflow Sure. Some algorithms that fast on lists are not so on vectors. OP specifically says he needs some implementation of list data structure.

Comment: @Cthulhu What algorithms? OP wants to build a list and then iterate over the elements. Sounds like a perfect job for `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cthulhu: It's not at all apparent that when the OP says "list" he specifically means "linked list". Given the requirements he has stated (collect CPoint objects then iterate over those objects), `std::vector` does sound like a substantially better fit than any sort of linked list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In which scenario do I use a particular STL Container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

Comment: Code shows new points being added to the *front* which, *if required*, is a point in favor of list over vector.

Comment: @dlf Not really. Just add to end and iterate backwards. Plus I don't think there's really specific requirement to add to front.

Comment: @dlf: If he really needed to add to the front (e.g., needs to add to both ends, in which case "add to the end and iterate backwards" isn't sufficient) that would favor `std::deque`, but still not really `std::list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend a `std::vector`. Also, there is no need for pointers here:

```
std::vector<CPoint> pointList;
// ...
pointList.emplace_back(x, y);
// ...
for (const CPoint& p : pointList)
{
    TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", p.x, p.y);
}
```

You seem to be using a very old C++ compiler. Try the following:

```
std::vector<CPoint> pointList;
// ...
pointList.push_back(CPoint(x, y));
// ...
for (std::vector<CPoint>::const_iterator it = pointList.begin();
                                        it != pointList.end(); ++it)
{
    TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", it->x, it->y);
}
```

Comment: My `std::vector` does not have a method `emplace_back`? Maybe I am using an older version of `std`?

Comment: Ok that works, and for the loop I get three errors. `error C2143: missing ',' before ':' error C2530: 'p' : references must be initialized error C2143: missing ';' before '{'`

Comment: You might also want to consider updating your compiler. VC++ has supported `emplace_back` for a while now.

Comment: If you're using a version of VC++ that doesn't support `emplace_back`, then it doesn't support the range-based `for` either. You could go back to your original idea of `std::for_each`, or use Microsoft's `for each(const CPoint& p in pointList)` language extension.

Comment: I'd upgrade everything, but alas, but my employer wishes to finish sawing down the tree before sharpening the blade. C# and Wpf? Nah 10+ year old MFC and C++. // Thank you @FredOverflow that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

To fix your compilation error, `#include <algorithm>` and change to :

```
std::for_each(pointList.begin(), pointList.end(), [](CPoint* cur)
{                                                   ^^^^^^^^
    TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", cur->x, cur->y);
});
```

Or more simply with a for range loop:

```
for(auto& p : pointList)
{
    TRACE("APoint: %f, %f\n", p->x, p->y);
}
```

**Note:**

- As for choosing a container Stick to Standard containers as long as you can, `std::list<>` is a good choice if you need a doubly linked list, but in your case an `std::vector<>` might just do it as well.
- Also see [In which scenario do I use a particular STL Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

Comment: @JerryCoffin how could that be ? Contiguous containers have to shuffle around half of their content, while a doubly-linked list just has four pointers to hook...

Comment: @Quentin Shuffle around half their content when?

Comment: @Quentin: In a vector you shuffle (on average) half the content to insert in the middle, so it's O(N). In a linked list, you have to walk through half the list on average to get to the insertion point, so it's *also* O(N) -- but being non-contiguous leads to poorer locality, so it makes poorer use of the cache.

Comment: @JerryCoffin you're measuring more than just the insertion then.

Comment: What are you guys talking about? Who wants to "insert in the middle"?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Probably nobody--he's just grasping at straws trying to justify continued advocacy for `std::list`.

Comment: @Quentin: I don't think so. I'm simply measuring *all* of the time necessary to do an insertion, and you're ignoring a large part of it in one case.

Comment: @FredOverflow quantdev originally adviced `std::list` for its insertion speed. Jerry argued against this, and deleted his comment afterwards.

Comment: @JerryCoffin one could argue that the insertion point is often already known (otherwise you're inserting blindly, which still must have its uses, but I can't think of any). Finding an element is another problem.