# How to make a list C++

Tags: c++

So I have to make a program that stores input piece by piece, until -1 is input. An example of this input would be 1 1 1 0 3 5 3 -1. And -1 would not be recorded. Then it plays the list back to you, but bacwards, so output would be 3 5 3 0 1 1 1

To do this I need to make a list of objects, but I have no clue how to declare them, or how to add/remove items to them. how do I do this?

Comment: take a look at `std::deque`.

Comment: @Wimmel `std::vector` would be better.

Comment: There are kinds of lists...

Comment: A stack is a good choice for reversing the order.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/471461/855869

Answer (score 2):

You need a place to store values that can grow as values are read.

The simpler is probably [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), but also `std::list` or `std::deque` as well as whatever bidirectional container will do the game.

Then you need a loop to get the values an save them into the container (the `push_back` method has that purpose), and another loop getting the values from the container from the end and printing them.

This can be done using iterators or using indexes, depending on the container and on your own specific needs.

This may be a possibility:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class V, class S>
void read_numbers(V& v, S& s, N end)
{
    N x=0;
    while(x << s)
    {
        if(x==end) return;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    std::cerr << "error: bad reading" << std::endl;
}

template<class V, class S>
void write_numbers(const V& v, S& s)
{
    for(auto i=s.rbegin(); i!=s.rend(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    read_numbers(nums, std::cin, -1); }
    write_numbers(nums, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a list of unknown size, you can declare a vector class:

```
  std::vector<int> myVector;
```

Then to add an element, use push_back:

```
  // assign some integer to myInt
   myVector.push_back (myInt);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Comment: But I can't add more then 7 items then, and the requirement is it HAS to be with a list.

Comment: fixed arrays to store variable input of unknown length ?

Comment: @Flotolk: The word _list_ has multiple meanings. It could mean a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). It could also mean a [sequence of numbers](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/list). You might want to clarify this.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia how do I do that?

Comment: @Flotolk, Emilio was just critiquing my answer.

Comment: @Gnuey: not anymore!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a list, then you could use `std::list`.
You can declare them like this:

```
std::list<int> myList;
```

You can read more about `std::list` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: Why not `std::vector<int>`? Seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: That's the most accurate answer, he said he needs a list, so a list it is. Although I'm pretty sure OP is expected to implement one himself, but he should have pointed it out.

Comment: @Leeor What BS. Just because a container happens to be called `std::list` doesn't mean it is the thing OP is after.

Comment: @juanchopanza, OP didn't say what he's after, and since he's learning c++, he probably isn't after *any* library implementation, so the question should be closed. But given the restrictions above, std list is just as good and utterly useless for him as the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for inspiration.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int number;

    do {
        std::cin >> number;
        if (number != -1) {
            numbers.push_back(number);
        }
    } while(number != -1);

    for (std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = numbers.rbegin(); it != numbers.rend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested already, you could use std::vector. It resizes as you push more elements. If the requirement is strictly a linked list, then go for std::list.

As to the requirement of playing them in reverse order, just use reverse_iterator and go through the list printing them.

```
std::list<int> mylist;
// Insert the elements.
for (std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rIt = mylist.rbegin();
     rIt != mylist.rend(); ++rIt) {
   cout << *rIt;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are basically two options:

1. You can use a pointer `int *data` and manually allocate memory to it with [`new[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). You'll need to continually reallocate the array as you find that the array is larger than you expected.
2. You can use one of the wonderful containers that c++ provides. I might suggest [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Here's an example of how you might implement this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data;

    while (true) {
        int number;
        std::cin >> number;
        if (!std::cin)
            break;
        if (number == -1)
            break;
        data.push_back(number);
    }

    for (int datum : data)
        std::cout << datum << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: malloc / realloc ?? in C11 at A.D. 2015 ?

Comment: @hyde: It's mostly a reflection of the lack of a realloc() alternative...

Comment: Well, realloc is theoretical optimization (in some situations) over just doing new allocation, and legacy C stuff IMO is not something a novice C++ programmer should learn, while still learning just programming in general (like seems to be the case here). Anyway, my downvote retracted.