# Trying to dynamically increase array size

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a program where a user keeps entering numbers, which are saved into an array, when the array is full I am trying to copy the original array into a new one one and continue to fill that array however I cannot get it to work at all. Here is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
        cout << "Please enter how many numbers you want to enter: ";
    cin >> size; 
    double *array = new double*[size];
    cout << "Please enter your numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
        if(i == size-1) {
            int newSize = 2*size;
            double *arrayb = new double*[newSize];
            for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
                arrayb[i] = array[i];
            }
            delete [] array;
            array = arrayb;
            size = newSize;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: The expression `new double*[size]` allocates an array of `size` *pointers* to `double`. On a 32-bit system this will lead to trouble.

Comment: And please elaborate on your problem? *How* can you not "get it to work at all"?  Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Stop this and use `std::vector`.

Comment: use a suitable container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get it to compile by making the double pointers point at doubles, instead of arrays of double pointers

```
int size;
cout << "Please enter how many numbers you want to enter: ";
cin >> size; 
double *array = new double[size];
//                        ^--- not pointers to doubles
cout << "Please enter your numbers: ";
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cin >> array[i];
    if(i == size-1) {
        int newSize = 2*size;
        double *arrayb = new double[newSize];
        //                         ^--- not pointers
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
            arrayb[i] = array[i];
        }
        delete [] array;
        array = arrayb;
        size = newSize;
    }
}
```

You have allocated enough memory in the first new for the data. 
*BUT* whn you get to one before the end of the current value of `size` you double the space you allocate. And make `size = newSize`. 
The outer `for` loop will never end, unless an exception gets thrown, for example a `bad::alloc` which is bound to happen eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the maximum size of your collection before execution you need to avoid array. Like TartanLlama says, you can use an std::vector. Vector allows you to add items as much as you want.
But there is plenty of container with different access method. See this link to have a first view of how choose your container : 
[In which scenario do I use a particular STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

Comment: You should choose a suitable container. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container

Answer (score 0):

If you read the compilation errors, you'll see the problem:

> ```
> g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -O2 -Weffc++      14226370.cpp    -o 14226370
> 14226370.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> 14226370.cpp:11:37: error: cannot convert ‘double**’ to ‘double*’ in initialization
>      double *array = new double*[size];
>                                      ^
> 14226370.cpp:17:49: error: cannot convert ‘double**’ to ‘double*’ in initialization
>              double *arrayb = new double*[newSize];
> ```

You are creating an array of pointers to double and attempting to initialise a single pointer to double, on both cases.

Looking at the way you use these, you probably meant to write `new double[size]` and `new double[newSize]`.