# STL container for simple image segmentation

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I need to segment an image, based on a simple rule (if value is in between 2 values). I'm using only STL containers (I'm not using opencv or other libraries because I want to keep this free of dependencies while teaching myself c++)

I've stored my images as `vector< vector<double> >`. My brute force approach is to iterate through my image using 2 iterators and check each value, and maybe push the indices of the values that satisfy my condition to another `vector<int>`. I'll have to do this until all segments are found. Every time I want to pick a segment I'll iterate through the stored indices.

1. What is the correct way to do this?
2. Can this be achieved in one pass?
3. What is a suitable STL container for this process? I'm trying to
   figure it out through this [flowchart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471461/2292650). The best I can come up
   with was an `unordered_multimap`.

Comment: vectors are great for images, but generally it works out better to use a `std::vector<double>` and then your index is `vec[currColumn*numRows + currRow]`. That way your image is in one, contiguous, cache-friendly piece of memory.

Comment: Good to know, I made it 2d purely for readability, nothing else, did not know the performance implications. will switch to 1d.

Comment: What do you mean by segment here?

Comment: similar to this [opencv python example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html). each coin would be a segment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving elements to the end of the vector, use `std::stable_partition`.

```
std::vector<int> vec(20);
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

std::iota(begin(vec), end(vec), 0);
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 

std::stable_partition(begin(vec), end(vec),
                      [](const auto& e){ return (4 <= e && e < 12);});
// 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 1 2 3 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

[Online example here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/taK0d2ExAvhDOAUK).

This will also work if you store the data in a single vector - use iterators for the beginning and end of the column/row instead of the entire range. I've got no idea how you read 'across' the data sensibly with either a 1D or 2D vector though!

(I wrote a very nice post about [Sean Parent's `gather` algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8) before realising it doesn't answer the question. View the edit history if you want to move selected items to places other than the ends.)

Answer (score -1):

If the image is divided to two segments, you can store the segmentation as `vector<vector<bool>>` with the same size as the image.