# Is there a container that I can add and remove from both ends

Tags: c++11, boost, stl, containers

Is there a container in C++ I could use to add elements in both ends, not just back or just front, but would like to add in either end. And similarly remove elements from any end, not from just one. Maybe in STLs or Boost?

Comment: what about `std::list`?

Comment: That would work perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: `std::deque`? If you need random access (say `at()` and/or `operator[]`) I suggest `std::deque`; otherwise I suppose `std::list` is a good choice.

Comment: Sure there are a few that support this.  Have a look at the STL flowchart in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container

Comment: @JustinRandall - nice flowchart; do you know something similar that support also C++11 containers (arrays, forward lists and unordered*)?

Comment: @max66 yes scroll further down past the accepted answer and you will see an updated flowchart for C++11.

Comment: @JustinRandall - Never stop at the first answer :( ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can portably add an element `x` to the front of a sequence container (`vector`/`deque`/`list`) via `v.insert(v.begin(), x)`.  However, for `vector` this is an O(n) operation (this is why `vector` does not have a convenient `push_front` operation) and it relocates all the existing elements.  If you don't want existing elements to be relocated, `deque` or `list` may be a better fit.

Comment: Please don't idly suggest `list`; `list` is a very special purpose container who is almost always a bad idea.