# (C++): Problem storing and accessing user login data

Tags: c++

This is simplification of my classes (a "gang-management" game logic):

```
class Player
{
private:
    string nickname, password;
    Gang my_gang; //this player's gang class instance
public:
    //generic functions...
}
//PlayerContainer is a database of all possible players, each player has a specific gang assigned
class PlayerContainer
{
private:
    list<Player> player_list;
public:
    void add_player();
    void remove_player();
    // and many more .....
    void login();
    void sign_up();
}
```

Now I wanted to test the login/sign up functionality in the console. In main, the program first asks a user for a login, or for a registration (new gang creation).

Following is the login() function definition (only the parts that I thought would be necessary):

```
//if login() returns false, the rest of the program won't continue. 
//If true is returned, the program forwards to the menu-part.

bool PlayerContainer::login()
{
    string nick, pass;

    cout << endl << "Enter your nickname: ";
    cin >> nick;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> pass;

    list<Player>::iterator it;

    for (it = player_list.begin(); it != player_list.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->get_nickname() == nick && it->get_password() == pass)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //breaks the loop and lets the function return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now the sign_up() function:

```
void PlayerContainer::sign_up()
{
    string nick, pass, gang_name;

    cout << endl << "Enter your nickname: ";
    cin >> nick;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> pass;

    list<Player>::iterator it;

    /*Check whether there are no known players*/
    for (it = player_list.begin(); it != player_list.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->get_nickname() == nick)
        {
            cout << endl << "ERROR: Player [" << it->get_nickname() << "] already exists!";
            return;
        }
    }

    cout << "\tCreate your gang" << endl << "Enter name of your gang: ";
    cin >> gang_name;

    Gang* g = new Gang(gang_name);

    Player* tmpp = new Player(nick, pass, *g);
    player_list.push_back(*tmpp); //store the temp player in the player list

    cout << endl << "Gang created successfully";
}
```

EXPECTATIONS:

- after signing up, the user "account" data should be stored in `list<Player> player_list`.

PROBLEM:

- when trying signing up after logging in, the login function won't evaluate true (won't let me in).

From what I tried by observing the code behaviour, it seems it's never really saved in `player_list`. It must have "slipped through". I'm blaming this part of code:

```
Player* tmpp = new Player(nick, pass, *g);
player_list.push_back(*tmpp); //store the temp player in the player list
```

I'd be very thankful for any insights!

Comment: Why are you using `new`, and not simply `player_list.push_back(Player(nick, pass, Gang(gang_name)));`?  Also, there is no need for `Gang` to be dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cpp
>     list<Player>::iterator it;
>
>     for (it = player_list.begin(); it != player_list.end(); ++it)
>     {
>         if (it->get_nickname() == nick && it->get_password() == pass)
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             //breaks the loop and lets the function return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```

The `else`-Block will break the search on the first mismatch. After you fixed your search functionality consider overloading `operator==()` and using `std::find()`.

---

Btw: `std::list<>` is almost always inappropriate. Use `std::deque<>` or `std::vector<>`. [In which scenario do I use a particular STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

---

Btw2:

> ```cpp
>    list<Player>::iterator it;
>
>    for (it = player_list.begin(); it != player_list.end(); ++it)
> ```

*~~>*

```cpp
for (auto it{ player_list.begin() }; it != player_list.end(); ++it) // ...
```

*~~>*

```cpp
for (auto const &player : player_list) // ...
```

---

Btw3: I don't know what your game will be like but I'd assume a gang would have multiple members and not every player wants to found it's own gang but rather join an existing one. Maybe you want to reconsider your data model.

Comment: Thanks very much! It worked 110%. Also, thank you for pointing out what I should improve. I'm still pretty new to c++ and I'm always up to find out new proper ways of using it. Thanks for your insight!
EDIT:Btw3: The players would be gang leaders and would fight against other players' gangs with their own. :-) But I know it still may have whole bunch of other flaws

Comment: @DemoVision Please also follow PaulMcKenzie's advice: `new` is hardly ever used in modern C++ (when you aren't writing libraries but user code). If you have to use dynamically created objects use a container or a smart pointer.